# Make signature fixed in Java / IntelliJ

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, jaxb

Is there a way in IntelliJ IDEA to make a signature/class/field fixed or generate a warning when a specific signature or field is changed?

Let me explain further.

When developing an application, usually multiple users are developing this application. The one user doesn't know about all the other's actions and or implementation details. Sometimes,... specific classes are chosen (for example) to serialize to some format (JSON) and these JSON representation are used by other (even external) applications.  These classes become fixed, because a change in one system has the effect the other system should change too. It would be great to have the possibility to indicate this class/method/field/... as being fixed, so IntelliJ will not change this, even if you do a rename/change signature/type migration or wathever. Or at least generate a warning of some kind.

I currently use technologies like generated classes (JAXB) for this particular situation, but it seems elaborate.

Comment: Use code reviews.

Comment: Or a test that fails if a method with the correct signature is missing. There are too many ways to change code in IntelliJ IDEA for anything like this to work.

Comment: You need to start thinking about versioning and revision management. There is no easy fix to the problem of evolving interfaces, which is what you're talking about.

Comment: @yole +1 for the test that fails. But I am not entirely convinced this is unfeasible...